# How to format the Body of a Mailto Message

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I am attempting to clean up the email output in this Mailto form so that it is more easily readable.  To do so I would like be able to pass the header fields into the email and format the output for easier reading.

This is my first attempt at creating an HTML based form.  I have it created so that the fields work they way I would like them to in the form itself but the mailto output is still very messy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name= "ReportRequest" action="mailto:cbostic@entirafamilyclinics.com?subject=Report Request" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

<Label><h1>Report Request Form</h1></Label> 
<br>

<Label><h2>Requestor Information:</h2></Label>
<br>

Date Requested: <input type="date" name="Date Requested:">
<br>

Email Address: <input type = "text" name = "Email Address:">
<br>

<script>
// Put this script in header or above select element
    function check(elem) {
        // use one of possible conditions
        if (elem.value == 'Adjust Current Report')
        //if (elem.selectedIndex == 1) 
        {
            document.getElementById("other-div").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("other-div2").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("other-div3").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("fre").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("ques").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("use").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("rec").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("format").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("patdet").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("excl").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("clinic").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("provider").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("age").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("daterange").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("diag").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("cptcode").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("visit").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("enc").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gender").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("reptyp").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("rephead").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("critq").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin6").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin7").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin8").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin9").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin10").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med6").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med7").style.display = 'none';
        } else 
        if (elem.value == 'Create New Report')
        {
            document.getElementById("other-div").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("other-div2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("other-div3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fre").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("ques").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("use").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("rec").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("format").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("patdet").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("excl").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("clinic").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("provider").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("age").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("daterange").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("diag").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("cptcode").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("visit").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("enc").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("gender").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("reptyp").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("rephead").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("critq").style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>

Type of Request:
 <select id="RequestType" name = "Type of Request:" onchange= "check(this);">
  <option value="Please Choose">Please Choose</option>
  <option value="Create New Report">Create New Report</option>
  <option value="Adjust Current Report">Adjust Current Report</option>
</select>
<br>

<div id="other-div" style="display:none">
Report Name: <input type = "text" name = "Report Name:">
</div>

<div id="other-div2" style="display:none">
Report Location(if known): <input type = "text" name = "Report Location:">
<br>
</div>

<div id="fre" style="display:none">
Report Frquency:
 <select name = "Report Frequency:">
  <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
  <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
  <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
  <option value="One Time">One Time</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<br>
</div>

Request Priority:
 <select name = "Report Priority:">
  <option value="Low">Low</option>
  <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
  <option value="High">High</option>
</select>
<br>

Deadline Date: <input type="date" name="Deadline Date:">
<br>

<Label><h2>Report Creation Questions:</h2></Label> 
<br>

<div id="ques" style="display:none">
Please Describe the question(s) you are attempting to answer:
<br>
<textarea rows = "5" cols = "50" name = "Please Describe the question(s) you are attempting to answer:">
 </textarea>
<br>
</div>

<div id="use" style="display:none">
How will the report be used?
<br>
<textarea rows = "5" cols = "50" name = "How will the report be used?">
 </textarea>
<br>
</div>

<div id="rec" style="display:none">
Who will receive the report?
<br>
<textarea rows = "5" cols = "50" name = "Who will receive the report?">
 </textarea>
<br>
</div>

<div id="format" style="display:none">
What format would you like the report in? (excel or pdf)
 <select name = "What format would you like the report in? (excel or pdf):">
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <option value="excel">Excel</option>
  <option value="PDF">PDF</option>
</select>
<br>
</div>

<div id="patdet" style="display:none">
Are patient details needed for this report?
<br>
<textarea rows = "5" cols = "50" name = "Are patient details needed for this report?">
 </textarea>
<br>
</div>

<div id="excl" style="display:none">
Does any data need to be excluded?
<br>
<textarea rows = "5" cols = "50" name = "Does any data need to be excluded?">
 </textarea>
<br>
</div>

<div id="other-div3" style="display:none;">
<label>What is being adjusted (if changing a current report)?
<br>
<textarea rows = "5" cols = "50" name = "What is being adjusted (if changing a current report)?">
</textarea>
</label>
<br>
</div>

<div id="critq" style="display:none">
<Label><h2>What Is the Criteria for the Report?</h2></Label> 
<br>

<Label>(Ex: Report only needs to be run for Shoreview Clinic, patients 6 years of age and older, with a diagnosis of asthma using CPT codes 1234, 5678)</Label> 
<br>
</div>

<div id="clinic" style="display:none;">
Clinics: <input type = "text" name = "Clinics:">
<br>
</div>

<div id="provider" style="display:none;">
Providers: <input type = "text" name = "Providers:">
<br>
</div>

<div id="age" style="display:none;">
Age Range: <input type = "text" name = "Age Range:">
<br>
</div>

<div id="daterange" style="display:none;">
Date Range: <input type = "text" name = "Date Range:">
<br>
</div>

<div id="diag" style="display:none;">
Diagnosis: <input type = "text" name = "Diagnosis:">
<br>
</div>

<div id="cptcode" style="display:none;">
CPT Code(s): <input type = "text" name = "CPT Code(s):">
<br>
</div>

<div id="visit" style="display:none;">
Visit Type(s): <input type = "text" name = "Visit Type(s):">
<br>
</div>

<div id="enc" style="display:none;">
Encounter Types: <input type = "text" name = "Encounter Types:">
<br>
</div>

<div id="gender" style="display:none;">
Gender: <input type = "text" name = "Gender:">
<br>
</div>

<script>
// Put this script in header or above select element
    function check2(elem2) {
        // use one of possible conditions
        if (elem2.value == 'Select')
        //if (elem.selectedIndex == 1)
         {
            document.getElementById("gen1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin6").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin7").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin8").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin9").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin10").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med6").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med7").style.display = 'none';
        }else
        if (elem2.value == 'general')
        {
            document.getElementById("gen1").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("gen2").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("gen3").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("gen4").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("gen5").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("fin1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin6").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin7").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin8").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin9").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin10").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med6").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med7").style.display = 'none';
        } else 
        if (elem2.value == 'Financial')
        {
            document.getElementById("gen1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin1").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("fin2").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("fin3").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("fin4").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("fin5").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("fin6").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("fin7").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("fin8").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("fin9").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("fin10").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("med1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med6").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med7").style.display = 'none';
        } else 
        if (elem2.value == 'Clinical')
        {
            document.getElementById("gen1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gen5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin1").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin2").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin3").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin4").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin5").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin6").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin7").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin8").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin9").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("fin10").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("med1").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("med2").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("med3").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("med4").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("med5").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("med6").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("med7").style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
<br>

<div id="reptyp" style="display:none">
Type of Report:
 <select name = "Type of Report:" onchange= "check2(this)">
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <option value="general">General</option>
  <option value="Financial">Financial/Billing</option>
  <option value="Clinical">Clinical/Medical</option>
</select>
<br>
</div>

<div id="rephead" style="display:none">
<Label><h2>What Headings Do You Want Displayed on Your Report?</h2></Label> 
<br>
</div>

<div id="gen1" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Primary Care Provider (PCP)" value= 'X'> Primary Care Provider (PCP)
</div>

<div id="gen2" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Appointment Provider" value= 'X'> Appointment Provider
</div>

<div id="gen3" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Encounter Date" value= 'X'> Encounter Date
</div>

<div id="gen4" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Appointment Facility" value= 'X'> Appointment Facility
</div>

<div id="gen5" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Insurance details" value= 'X'> Insurance details
</div>
<br>
<div id="fin1" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Claim Number" value= 'X'> Claim Number
</div>

<div id="fin2" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Claim Date" value= 'X'> Claim Date
</div>

<div id="fin3" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Service Date" value= 'X'> Service Date
</div>

<div id="fin4" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Appointment Facility" value= 'X'> Appointment Facility
</div>

<div id="fin5" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Appointment Provider" value= 'X'> Appointment Provider
</div>

<div id="fin6" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "ICD Codes" value= 'X'> ICD Codes
</div>

<div id="fin7" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "CPT/HCPCS Codes" value= 'X'> CPT/HCPCS Codes
</div>

<div id="fin8" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Insurance Names" value= 'X'> Insurance Names
</div>

<div id="fin9" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Billed Amount" value= 'X'> Billed Amount
</div>

<div id="fin10" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Amount Paid By Insurance" value= 'X'> Amount Paid By Insurance
</div>
<br>
<div id="med1" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Allergies" value= 'X'> Allergies
</div>

<div id="med2" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "ICD Codes" value= 'X'> ICD Codes
</div>

<div id="med3" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "CPT/HCPCS Codes" value= 'X'> CPT/HCPCS Codes
</div>

<div id="med4" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Advanced Directives" value= 'X'> Advanced Directives
</div>

<div id="med5" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Problem List" value= 'X'> Problem List
</div>

<div id="med6" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Medications" value= 'X'> Medications
</div>

<div id="med7" style="display:none">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "Referrals" value= 'X'> Referrals
</div>
<br>
<Label><h2>Additional information regarding your request:</h2></Label> 
<br>
<textarea rows = "5" cols = "50" name = "Additional information regarding your request:">
 </textarea>
 <br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect a well formatted email output including the form headers that would be easily readable.

Comment: With a mailto action, you're generating a form that then opens a new email window  in the user's email program, which is unreliable, insecure, and can not be formatted.   To nicely format the email, you would need to have a back end script that you post to, which builds the email and sends it.  If you don't have easy access to build a back end script on your site, there are third party email services that you can use to do this as well...

Comment: Would a PHP mail script work better for what I am trying to do then or is there an even better option?

Comment: A PHP script would be perfect...

Comment: Okay, I will create a PHP script for it then.  Thank you for the information!

Comment: @CBos - Yes a PHP script would be the best way to achieve what you're after. This [tutorial](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-create-an-ajaxphp-contact-form) should help.